# Ruby pointing to system ruby rather than rvm in ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I use ubuntu `11.10` and I have installed rvm and have installed `ruby 1.9.3`. My system has by default `ruby 1.9.1`. Hence instead of pointing to the ruby installed by rvm, my system points to the default ruby. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Did you do `rvm use --default 1.9.3`?

Comment: @Dogbert, I have tried it and it didnt work.

Comment: RVM works by injecting itself as the first entry in your `PATH`. In order to do this you need to run the RVM setup in your bash profile. Did you do this step when you installed RVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet that you haven't configured your path correctly. Try

```
echo $PATH
```

Ive got

```
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin
```

before

```
/usr/bin
```

If that isnt the case for you, then you can add this little script to your .bashrc

I do this because sometimes I want to use system ruby and sometimes I want to use rvm rubies.

```
rvmenv() {
    [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.                                                                           
}
#rvmenv
```

If you want to use rvm all the time you can just uncomment the last line, or you can just run

```
rvmenv
```

in a shell session.

Answer (score 1):

RVM requires you to use login shell, it is not turned on by default so you need to do it manually https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/